# Specific dependency classes not recognized

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dependencies

I started working on a maven project in Netbeans and a few weeks later my code started randomly erroring.  Turns out the IDE randomly stopped recognizing the specific classes I have been working with. This is probably some super basic Java problem that can be fixed with proper practice but I feel like I needed help with this.

Code of erroring class:

```
package me.mafrans.plm.httpd.pages;

import com.commodore.pixellibertymod.rank.Rank; // This is the import that is erroring
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import me.mafrans.plm.httpd.util.PUtil;

public class index implements WebPage
{
    @Override
    public String[] getPages()
    {
        return new String[] {"index", "header", "header_style.css"};
    }

    @Override
    public String getHTML(String url, Map<String,String> params, Rank userrank)
    {
        try
        {
            return PUtil.getHtmlFile("index");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "<html><body style=\"font-family:Arial\"><h1 style=\"text-align:center;\">404</h1>\n"
                + "<p style=\"text-align:center;\">This page could not be found, maybe it's down for the moment?</p>\n"
                + "</body></html>";
    }
}
```

As you can see on the screenshot Rank.class clearly exists:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H19fX.png)

What I have tried:
 - Restarting netbeans
 - Clearing netbeans cache
 - Readding dependencies
 - Using shaded dependencies
 - Removing Roaming/Netbeans folder

Also, when allowing netbeans to autocomplete the class it only shows the Displayable class: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmK2v.png)

Comment: IDEs don't do things "randomly".  You've done something wrong.  The fact that you have a class that has hard coded HTML markup suggests that have a lot to learn.  You need to add that dependency to your Maven pom.xml.

Comment: thank you for commenting, i do have a lot to learn as I am very young and has only coded in java for about a year, the dependency is in the pom.xml already and has worked before but suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Lesson 1 for programmers: nothing is random. The code isn't persecuting you. You did something wrong and have to fix it. It's always your fault. Something changed. I'd advise that you not use Maven. It's another big unknown. Better to get the JARs manually, add them to a /Lin directory, and tell NetBeans to add it to CLASSPATH.

Comment: I am sure the dependency is correctly added into the pom, do you have any information about the problem itself as I believe the inexperience problems will fix themselves with time.

Comment: The JVM disagrees with you. Where is the JAR that contains that class?  How does NetBeans tell the JVM about it at runtime?

Comment: The assumption you are doing everything correctly is your biggest barrier to fixing this.

Comment: I agree you are correct but I believe I need help with identifying what I am not doing correctly as I do not see any difference between the dependencies that work correctly and the dependency that does not work correctly.
A copy of the pom can be found at <https://hastebin.com/bimovahofa.xml>, please note that "pixellibertymod" is the only dependency that is not working correctly.

Comment: Forget the Pom.xml. Where is that JAR?  Can you see it in the Maven repo?  If not, it won't be pulled to your machine.

Comment: The jar is found in a local directory as well as the other dependencies that are not part of a maven repository [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/9b0df215204dc1afcfb1013eae0e0ef5.png)

Comment: "JAR is found in local directory" - did you put it there?  Is that directory in your CLASSPATH?  Does NetBeans know to look there for JARs?  Is the class that's not importing in the JAR?  Can you see it?

Comment: did you put it there? Yes, I did.  
Is that directory in your CLASSPATH? No, it is not but since I am not running the java file it should not be a problem (according to my knowledge).  
Does NetBeans know to look there for JARs? Yes, it does  
Is the class that's not importing in the JAR? Can you see it? Yes and yes  
  
As I said only specific classes are unusable, the rest of the dependency works fine.

Comment: Then Maven had NOTHING to do with it.  Doesn't matter what your pom.xml says.  Is that /lib directory in your CLASSPATH?  If not, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was all Netbeans fault as the problem was nowhere to be seen when using another IDE like IntelliJ IDEA